# .NET web API POST status error 415 unsupported media type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-415

Coded a category controller and API that posts Title, Type and Icon but it is giving status 415 error (unsupported media type). I am trying to get my backend talking to a Python frontend.
need suggestion on what I have done wrong.

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ExpenseTracker.Models;

namespace ExpenseTracker.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public CategoryController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Category
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return _context.Categories != null ?
                        View(await _context.Categories.ToListAsync()) :
                        Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Categories'  is null.");
        }

        // GET: Category/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Categories == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var category = await _context.Categories
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CategoryId == id);
            if (category == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Category/AddOrEdit
        public IActionResult AddOrEdit(int id = 0)
        {
            if (id == 0)
                return View(new Category());
            else
                return View(_context.Categories.Find(id));
        }

        // POST: Category/AddOrEdit
        
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit([Bind("CategoryId,Title,Icon,Type")] Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (category.CategoryId == 0)
                    _context.Add(category);
                else
                    _context.Update(category);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Category/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Categories == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var category = await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id);
            if (category == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Category/Edit/5
        
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("CategoryId,Title,Icon,Type")] Category category)
        {
            if (id != category.CategoryId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(category);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!CategoryExists(category.CategoryId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(category);
        }

        // GET: Category/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Categories == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var category = await _context.Categories
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CategoryId == id);
            if (category == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(category);
        }

        // POST: Category/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Categories == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDbContext.Categories'  is null.");
            }
            var category = await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id);
            if (category != null)
            {
                _context.Categories.Remove(category);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool CategoryExists(int id)
        {
            return (_context.Categories?.Any(e => e.CategoryId == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

This is API and as far as I know, API looks fine to me but I am getting 415 status error

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ExpenseTracker.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ExpenseTracker.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ApiCategoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ApiCategoryController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/ApiCategory
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Category>>> GetCategories()
        {
            return await _context.Categories.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/ApiCategory/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Category>> GetCategory(int id)
        {
            var category = await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id);

            if (category == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return category;
        }

        // POST: api/ApiCategory
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Category>> PostCategory(Category category)
        {
            _context.Categories.Add(category);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetCategory), new { id = category.CategoryId }, category);
        }

        // PUT: api/ApiCategory/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutCategory(int id, Category category)
        {
            if (id != category.CategoryId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CategoryExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // DELETE: api/ApiCategory/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCategory(int id)
        {
            var category = await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id);
            if (category == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Categories.Remove(category);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool CategoryExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Categories.Any(e => e.CategoryId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

```
Tried postman and changed the content-type but not working. I am not sure what I have written wrong in the category controller. This is what the client is sending in python


    from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
    import requests
    
    categories_bp = Blueprint('categories', __name__)
    
    @categories_bp.route('/categories', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def categories():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            income = request.form['income']
            expense = request.form['expense']
            title = request.form['title']
            icon = request.form['icon']
    
            response = requests.post('https://localhost:7005/api/apicategory', json ={
                'income': income,
                'expense': expense,
                'title': title,
                'icon': icon
            }, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
            
            if response.ok:
                return 'Category Added'
            else: 
                return 'Failed to add category'
    
        else:    
            return render_template("categories.html")
```

Comment: That response code implies that the client is POSTing using some content type or encoding that the server doesn’t support. The problem can’t be diagnosed without knowing what the client is sending.

Comment: I have just added what the client is sending

Answer (score 0):

Using Python Requests Library, the json parameter automatically converts it to JSON string. Also, the Request Library automatically adds the Content-Type: application/json header to your request when using the json. [Refer here](https://reqbin.com/code/python/m2g4va4a/python-requests-post-json-example)

If you want to use ContentType explicitly, you can use "data" parameters passing below header values.
headers = {"charset": "utf-8", "Content-Type": "application/json"}